# Regex with [^.. ] not working in Mac OS

Tags: bash, grep, osx-yosemite

Here is my test:
rich$ cat foofile

```
abc
def
aef
bde
```

> richadminsMini:~ rich$ file foofile

```
foofile: ASCII text
```

> richadminsMini:~ rich$ ggrep -V
>       ggrep (GNU grep) 2.26
>       Packaged by Homebrew
>       Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> richadminsMini:~ rich$ ggrep 'b' foofile

```
abc
bde
```

> richadminsMini:~ rich$ ggrep 'a' foofile

```
abc
aef

richadminsMini:~ rich$ ggrep '[ab]' foofile 
abc
aef
bde
richadminsMini:~ rich$ ggrep '[^ab]' foofile 
abc
def
aef
bde
```

I expected lines 1, 3 and 4 to be excluded ...
My shell is bash. What's up?

Answer (score 1):

Either invert a positive expression with `grep -v '[ab]'`, or change your regular expression to do a full match, i.e. `grep -E '^([^ab]+)$'`.

The problem is that you are looking for partial matches of things not having a or b. In the case of abc, for example, that matches 'c', so the line is included.

You can use the default platform `grep`. That's not the problem.

Comment: Just to add to what Jameson wrote, your ggrep is looking for "Any line that has any non-a or non-b character somewhere/anywhere in it." So the only kinds of lines that would not have been returned would look like "a", "aa" "baba", etc.